# API for getting a type of surface (road/forest/park) from coordinates

Tags: api, location, geo

I'm creating an Android app which records bike routes using GPS. Unfortunately when I ride along streets, the GPS sensor is not so accurate to display its results exactly on the streets but usually next to the street (black line in the picture).

[image: route]

I have an idea to check if routes are near to a road and modify these routes in order to display expected routes (red line)

**Is there a free(or barely free) API to get a type of surface (at least is it a road there or not) having coordinates (e.g. 52.22169208516709, 20.98473942569997)?**

I was looking for it in Open Street Maps (using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)) and I've found only `around` selector, but it has no dataset for minor streets in my area. I need data for Europe.